# How do I write a JSON_TABLE query in php?

Tags: php, json, mysqli

I am running this query in phpmyadmin (mysql 8.0.13):

```
SELECT people.* FROM product, JSON_TABLE(attributes, '$.people[*]' COLUMNS (firstname VARCHAR(40) PATH '$."firstname"')) people
```

It works as expected but when I try the same query in php nothing works.

```
$result = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT people.* FROM product, JSON_TABLE(attributes, '$.people[*]' COLUMNS (firstname VARCHAR(40) PATH '$."firstname"')) people");
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
    {
    $firstname = $row['firstname'];
    }
```

Can someone please tell me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: maybe the $ symbol gets interpreted as PHP variable? Try to put the SQL in single quotes instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$result = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT people.* FROM product, JSON_TABLE(attributes, '$.people[*]' COLUMNS (firstname VARCHAR(40) PATH '$.firstname')) people");
```

You had a syntax error in your query. You mixed double and single quotes in the firstname. Give a try to the above query and let me know if it works.